# React Native - focus the first touchable in a list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get the first `TouchableOpacity` in a `FlatList` to get focus after render. I tried to use refs and trigger focus from `useEffect` but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import {FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";

const MyScreen = () => {
    const refs = useRef([]);

    useEffect (() => {
        refs.current[0].focus()
    }, []);

    const setFocusedElement = (element) => {
        console.log(element);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={[1, 2, 3]}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity ref={el => refs.current[index] = el} onFocus={() => setFocusedElement(item)}>
                            <View><Text>{item}</Text></View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default MyScreen;
```

I'm getting an error like so : "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refs.current[0].focus')"

[EDIT] after a small edit based on @drew-reese great answer, the ref is working, but the focus still isn't.

[EDIT 2] Here is a snack example of the issue : https://snack.expo.dev/@jerrybels/calm-ramen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refs` itself is a React ref, but you don't appear to be setting the child refs by index correctly. You should still reference `refs.current` to update the ref value.

```
ref={el => refs.current[index] = el}
```

You may find you have better luck explicitly creating refs for each child component being rendered, and pass these *as* the ref versus using the callback syntax.

```
const refs = useRef([]);

refs.current = data.map((_, i) => refs.current[i] ?? createRef());

useEffect (() => {
  refs.current[0].current.focus();
}, []);

...

<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity ref={refs.current[index]}>
      <View><Text>{item}</Text></View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Hey, great answer! Although, the data is loaded async so I can't really create thee refs ahead of time... With the callback syntax, it now works a little better but the focus still won't work (no focus) if I'm using `refs.current[0].focus();` and will throw an error about undefined not being an object if I try `refs.current[0].current.focus();`

Comment: Also, I can't create the refs in a `useEffect` function watching for changes on the async loaded data since `useEffect` is called after render took place anyway...

Comment: @JeremyBelolo The `refs.current` in the function body should handle generating refs for each element in the "data" array. This occurs each and every render cycle, it maps the "data" and creates new refs if they don't exist yet, otherwise uses the ref generated previously. If `data` is loaded asynchronously then you don't want to use an empty dependency array, you'll want to add your "data" as a dependency. To guard against null accesses you can use Optional Chaining, i.e. `refs.current[0]?.focus();`. Can you provide a more accurate code example that represents your use case?

Comment: I will try your suggestions and come back with a more accurate example if needed, thanks!

Comment: There you go @drew-reese, I tried and played around with your suggestions for two days and can't figure out what's wrong. Fact : the element is not focused. Here is a complete example : https://snack.expo.dev/@jerrybels/calm-ramen

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Try https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/calm-ramen. It fixes setting the refs and focuses on the first element in the array instead of the second.

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you! I understood the mistakes I made. But, of course, it couldn't work in my project - that would be too simple. If I'm using the same code on the App component of my project, it works, but if it's the exact same code on another component that's navigated to, the focus isn't done. I can't understand why and that's making me crazy. I will continue to dig around this, and if nothing comes out of it I will prepare a snack or a repo with a ready to debug MCVE. Thanks again.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Welcome. Has my answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your current posted question/issue?

Comment: Hey, I was about to answer that you did, but actually the issue exists in your version as well - try to open the snack on Android instead of web, and it won't work as intended

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Sorry, that was a multitask fail. Meant for it to say, "Will do, checking it out now." So far from what I can see, the refs aren't populated, so I'm looking at that.

Comment: Yes I saw the same thing. Console logging says that there are multiple rendering but the last value shown seems fine...

Comment: I wanted to reduce the complexity as much as possible... Her ewe go, it's not even working like this https://snack.expo.dev/@jerrybels/frisky-waffle web is fine but Android is not focused

Comment: Since you technically answered this question, I validated the answer and opened a new one here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009024/react-native-focus-a-touchable-in-useeffect-working-on-web-but-not-android - I also opened a bug report in the RN repo, since it looks like a bug to me

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Ok, thanks. I'll take a look at your new post.