# React Native - focus a touchable in useEffect working on web but not Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, use-effect, touchableopacity

I'm trying to get a TouchableOpacity to get focus after render. I tried to use refs and trigger focus from useEffect. It works on a web browser but not an Android device - the focus is never called.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Text,TouchableOpacity,View} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(0);
  const touchableRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    touchableRef.current?.focus();
  }, []);

  const setFocusedElement = () => {
    setFocused(1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity ref={touchableRef} onFocus={() => setFocusedElement()}>
        <Text>Hello, I should be focused. {focused}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is a snack showing the issue. You can see that it focuses on web but not on an Android device. https://snack.expo.dev/@jerrybels/frisky-waffle

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Actually not, and they simply closed my issue I opened on github. I used https://github.com/ds300/patch-package to patch rn myself and force it to behave the way I wanted - dirty but did the trick for me